# TypeScript: interface method implementation

Tags: typescript, methods, interface

How to implement a method in an interface in TypeScript?

```
interface Bar
{
    num: number;
    str: string;
    fun?(): void;
}
class Bar
{
    fun?()
    {
        console.log(this.num, this.str);
    }
}
let foo: Bar = {num: 2, str: "B"};
foo.fun();
```

Expected: `2 B`

Actual:

```
Error Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
```

If the optional flag is omitted from the method `fun()`, then the error will be:

```
Property 'fun' is missing in type '{ num: number; str: string; }' but required in type 'Bar'.ts(2741)
```

## Update 1

This is a work-around that results in what is expected, though it does not seem like the proper way to do this.

```
if(foo.fun)
{
    foo.fun();
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Implement the interface in the class you are creating and then invoke.

```
interface BarInterface
{
    num: number;
    str: string;
    fun: () => void;
}

class Bar implements BarInterface {
    num: number;
    str: string;

    constructor(num: number, str: string) {
        this.num = num;
        this.str = str;
    }
    fun() {
        console.log(this.num, this.str);
    }
}

let foo = new Bar(2, "B");

foo.fun();
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript tells you that it is undefined because you did not provide a method to invoke in this line:

```
let foo: Bar = {num: 2, str: "B"};
```

Try

```
const myTestFun = () => {
  console.log('I am here!')
}
let foo: Bar = {num: 2, str: "B", fun: myTestFun };
```